# Switch case goes to default value straight away

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object with arrays (the numbers are codes I get from API):

```
const weatherConditions = {
    rainy: [365, 362, 359, 356, 353, 320, 317, 314, 311, 308, 305, 302, 299, 296, 293, 284, 281, 266, 263, 185, 182, 176, 143],
    snowy: [371, 368, 338, 335, 332, 329, 326, 323, 230, 227, 179],
    sunny: [113],
    partlyCloudy: [116],
    cloudy: [122, 119],
    foggy: [260, 248],
    storm: [395, 392, 389, 386],
    thunder: [200],
    hailing: [377, 374, 350],
};
```

A function that runs through the object keys and finds the number the API sent. It returns a string value of the object key (sunny, cloudy etc.):

```
const findByCode = (code) => {
        console.log(
            Object.keys(weatherConditions).find((key) => {
                return weatherConditions[key].includes(code);
            }),
        );
    };
```

A switch case, that chooses a picture respectively the function return value. But it always runs to default straight away. I don't see the issue. (weatherCode is an API value, 100% correct);

```
switch (findByCode(weatherCode)) {
        case 'rainy':
            img.src = './img/rain.png';
            break;
        case 'snowy':
            img.src = './img/snow.png';
            break;
        case 'sunny':
            img.src = './img/sun.png';
            break;
        case 'partlyCloudy':
            img.src = './img/partly-cloudy.png';
            break;
        case 'cloudy':
            img.src = './img/clouds.png';
            break;
        case 'foggy':
            img.src = './img/fog.png';
            break;
        case 'storm':
            img.src = './img/storm.png';
            break;
        case 'thunder':
            img.src = './img/thunder.png';
            break;
        case 'hailing':
            img.src = './img/hail.png';
            break;
        default:
            img.src = './img/weather-news.png'
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `findByCode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `console.log()` is the problem in `findByCode` replace it with a `return` statement and it will work.

Comment: Thank you. It was the issue